# re.compile not obeying case of text when using with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup and currently looping through a series of `li` objects and the two that are causing me issues are the following two:

```
<li><span class="prefix">Teams</span>6</li>
<li><span class="prefix">New teams</span>4</li>
```

I'm matching based on `.find` as seen below:

```
if newdetail.find(text=re.compile("Teams")):
```

However for some reason `re.compile` is registering each of the `li` objects under this if statement, I want to make it case sensitive so that it ONLY finds the following:

```
<li><span class="prefix">Teams</span> 6</li>
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem. When using your example HTML with `soup.findAll(text=re.compile(r'Teams'))` I get `[u'Teams']` as result.

Comment: What do you actually do under your `if newdetail.find(...):` statement? As it is, if the `newdetail` is the parsed abovementioned piece of HTML, then of course this will always match as it contains a 'Teams' string, doesn't matter on which line, and the `if` condition will be `True`.

Comment: Do you want to loop through all the `<li>` items and only act on the required one?

Comment: @famousgarkin I want to loop through all of the `<li>` items and do certain things for ones that have specific terms/regex patterns, like for the `Teams` one I do some math on the number, currently im retreiving the number by doing: `result_team = newdetail.get_text().replace("Team", "").strip()` The problem is that the html that im parsing doesnt always have the same html parts so they have to be if statements and they are never in the same order. I'm sure I could make it more efficient by skipping the looping part and finding the exact part... but i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the html that im parsing doesnt always have the same html parts

I'm not sure if you mean the information you need will not always be in lists and spans, or what, but here's how I parsed your data and extracted the totals I wanted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_filename = "tester.html"
html_file = open(page_filename, 'r').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

lists = soup.find_all('li')

for item in lists:
    span = item.find('span')
    if "Teams" in span.string:
        span.replaceWith('')
        print item.text
```

If Teams and Total are always together in a line but not necessarily in lists or spans, or they are not consistently associated in the same way within the line, you will have problems getting what you want. Ideally you would determine all patterns that Team and Total can be found with, use BS4's built-in methods to find matches, and use regex to get you the rest of the way if needed.